# difficulties with finding the names that have dot in them with grep

Tags: r, grepl

I have difficulties finding the names that have dot in them with grep. it cannot find them. i do not have any problem with non dotted names. 
I mean names such as: "J.D. Drew", i have tried the following code:

```
grepl("J.D. Drew" ,data_player$name)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `fixed = TRUE` in `grepl()` when you are looking for exact strings.  It's faster too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape those dots. Because `grepl` (*without `fixed=TRUE` argument*) should accept regex as first argument. Dot's in regex matches any character. IN-order to match literal dot's, you need to escape them in the regex part. Or you may use char class for treating those as literal ones like `[.]`

```
grepl("J\\.D\\. Drew" ,data_player$name)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually my grep is in a loop that gets a string each time. I want it to be automatically, because i don't know how many dotted name are in my 1000 names

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this to find any name (string) in your variable with a dot in it?

```
# example data frame
data_player <- data.frame(name=c("Judith","J.D.Drew","S.Harris","Simon"),stringsAsFactors = F)

# version 1 with your mentioned loop
for(i in 1:nrow(data_player)){
  if(grepl("(\\.)+",data_player$name[i])) print(data_player$name[i])
}

# version 2 without a loop
data_player$name[which(grepl("(\\.)+",data_player$name))]
```

Hope this helps!